# ElementNotInteractableException: When sending Arrow Up to a number input with Selenium in Java

Tags: java, selenium

I'm inputting a salary in to a tax calculator website but it requires an arrow_up or arrow_down to be sent for it to actually calculate the tax amounts (in lieu of the enter key). I've read online that I ought to be able to send keys.ARROW_UP or keys.ARROW_DOWN but this results in

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'salaryDataLoader': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.openqa.selenium.ElementNotInteractableException: element not interactable
```

The relevant code is as follows:

```
        //Works fine and inputs salary number
        WebDriverManager.chromedriver().setup();
        ChromeDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
        String taxSiteUrl = "https://www.icalculator.info/estonia.html";
        driver.get(taxSiteUrl);
        WebElement salaryInput = driver.findElement(By.id("j2"));  number
        JavascriptExecutor jExec = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
        String executionScript = String.format("arguments[0].value='%s';", "25000");
        jExec.executeScript(executionScript, salaryInput);

        //Attempt to force calculations by hitting up and then down arrow on number input
        salaryInput.sendKeys(Keys.ARROW_UP);
        salaryInput.sendKeys(Keys.ARROW_DOWN);
        String taxPayableXPath = "//*[@id=\"taxResults\"]/table[1]/tbody/tr[4]/td[1]";
        double taxPayable = Double.parseDouble(driver.findElement(By.xpath(taxPayableXPath)).getText());
```

The input I am targeting is

```
<input type="number" id="j2" name="j2" value="80000" min="0" step="0.01">
```

Comment: in certain browsers (I think it's Chrome) the number input takes those events.  (it increments type="number" inputs when up/down arrow is used...)  So the site shouldn't rely on arrow keys for forcing a calculation (since this will only increment/decrement).  Another issue might be if autosuggest attribute is not set to false and the type="text".  (It defaults to true for type="text" methinks...)

Comment: This is in chrome but it isn't taking them unfortunately. Not too sure what you mean about autosuggest attribute and how I might turn it off/fix it?

Comment: Right-click on the element you are targeting and choose, "Inspect". Add that markup to your post. (ex: <input type='number'>) What I mean by the browser taking those events is that they may not available to Selenium or Javascript. (The event is handled by the browser component and it will increment/decrement for type=number...) To turn off autosuggest in an input you'd add the "autocomplete" attribute. (I got the name wrong before... ex: <input type='text' autocomplete='false'>)

Comment: I've added the input to the post there. I dont actually have control over the site I'm using, so would I need to be using selenium to edit the webpage's html itself to add autocomplete='false' somehow and then this might help my issue?

Comment: not sure that autocomplete would be the issue for type="number".  Try the answer below... if that doesn't help it's because of the custom input control that Chrome supplies.  Use a method that doesn't send up/down keys.

Comment: It's also possible that a small sleep between the up and down key would help here.  (Chrome will take a little time to increment and then set focus back to the input...)

Answer (score 0):

You can use Implicit wait :
`driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(50, TimeUnit.SECONDS);`

And Explicit wait :
`WebDriverWait wait=new WebDriverWait(driver, 20); element = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath(taxPayableXPath)));`

**code:**

```
//Works fine and inputs salary number
        WebDriverManager.chromedriver().setup();
        ChromeDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
        String taxSiteUrl = "https://www.icalculator.info/estonia.html";
        driver.get(taxSiteUrl);
        WebElement salaryInput = driver.findElement(By.id("j2"));  number
        JavascriptExecutor jExec = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
        String executionScript = String.format("arguments[0].value='%s';", "25000");
        jExec.executeScript(executionScript, salaryInput);

WebDriverWait wait=new WebDriverWait(driver, 20); element = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath(taxPayableXPath)));

        //Attempt to force calculations by hitting up and then down arrow on number input
        salaryInput.sendKeys(Keys.ARROW_UP);
        salaryInput.sendKeys(Keys.ARROW_DOWN);
        String taxPayableXPath = "//*[@id=\"taxResults\"]/table[1]/tbody/tr[4]/td[1]";
        double taxPayable = Double.parseDouble(driver.findElement(By.xpath(taxPayableXPath)).getText());
```